# How to debug a jQuery autocomplete that is showing only one result?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am new in JS programming. I have designed a jQuery autocomplete functionality in which when user search in search box then matched result will displayed in highlighted text.

But in my code I have a problem: it is displaying search result while searching but it show only first row text highlighted. Other matching result text are not highlighted. Also when I click matched result then list should disappear but list is not disappearing.

Here is my code with HTML and jQuery autocomplete:

**HTML Code:-**

```js
(function($) {

  var $project = $('#project');

  var projects = [

    {
      value: "Aditi Deshpande",
      icon: "img-profile-pic-lms.png"
    },
    {
      value: "Aarti Roy",
      icon: "img-profile-pic-lms.png"
    },
    {
      value: "Athiya Patil",
      icon: "img-profile-pic-lms.png"
    },
    {
      value: "Priyanka Deshmukh",
      icon: "img-profile-pic-lms.png"
    },
    {
      value: "Priya Sharma",
      icon: "img-profile-pic-lms.png"
    }
  ];
  var temp = true;
  $project.autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    source: projects,
    select: function(event, ui) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $project.val(ui.item.label);
      temp = true;
      return false;
    },
    focus: function(event, ui) {
      if (temp) {
        $(this).autocomplete("search");
        temp = false;
      }

    },
    open: function(e, ui) {
      var acData = $(this).data('ui-autocomplete');
      acData
        .menu
        .element
        .find('a')
        .each(function() {
          var me = $('#this');
          var keywords = acData.term.split(' ').join('|');
          me.html(me.text().replace(new RegExp("(" + keywords + ")", "gi"), '<b>$1</b>'));
        });
    }
  });
  $project.data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    var $li = $('<li>');
    var $img = $('<img>');
    $img.attr({
      src: '../../images/' + item.icon,
      alt: item.label
    });
    $li.attr('data-value', item.label);
    $li.append('<a href="#">');
    $li.find('a').append($img).append("<span id='this'>      </span>")
    $li.find('a').append($img).find("span").append(item.label);
    return $li.appendTo(ul);
  };
  $('#project').autocomplete("search", "");
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="resDiv">
  <div class="searchbox" id="project-    label">
    <input id="project" type="text" value="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you add jsFiddle ?

Comment: or click `<>` and add a snippet here

Comment: Put simply: only use `id=` for a single element (id must be unique).  So when you do ` var me = $('#this');` it gets the first one as there should only be one.  Change that line to ` var me = $("span", this);`

Comment: @halfer the edit is just putting it in a snippet - no other edit - didn't fix title/grammar/spelling etc

Comment: Hi, third comment really helpful and it solve my first issue. but second issue is not resolved. After selecting any matched result, the dropdown menu should be disappear. Please help me sorting this issue. Thanks for help.

Comment: Rahul, please use useful titles in any programming forum - "please help me" is of no use to readers wondering whether to click on your question. It reads a bit like a begging message as well - we know you want help, and a useful title is a good step towards getting you the help you need. Help your readers to help you! Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking another question.

Comment: @halfer I just add runable example on my edit

Comment: Ok Sir. Can you give me some idea after reading my jquery above code  that why dropdown list is not disappear after clicking on any matched reult. Thanks for help.